# audio validation issues laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate my form request. What I'm doing is I am to upload audio, that is, mp3,wav etc, the issue I'm having is that it keeps throwing an error message back at me saying 'the file type must be mp3', I tried uploading an image and it said the file type must be mp3, I also tried uploading mp3 and it says the same thing, below is my audio controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
public function uploadsingle(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'song' => 'required|mimes:image/png',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    ///save audio, etc
    echo 'validation passed';
}
}
```

this is my html code

```
<title>Upload page</title>
@include('layouts.page-life')
@include('layouts.navbar')




<h1>Upload Page</h1>
<br>
<form action="{{ route('doupload') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
@if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <ul>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif

<input name="song" type="file"/>
<br>
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following validation will accept wav, mp3 etc. This code is working for me.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'song' => 'required|mimes:application/octet-stream,audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav',
]);
```

or write it in separate request file: eg: `app/Http/Requests/SongStoreRequest.php`

```
public function rules(){
  ['song' => 'required|mimes:application/octet-stream,audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav'];
}
```

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is a generic mime type and has nothing to do with audio validation at all.

Comment: @emix Actually, it seems Laravel incorrectly identifies ogg files as octet-stream so that is probably why he included it in his validator.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538962/laravel-7-incorrect-mime-type-detected

Comment: Still, it's just a workaround, not a fix of any kind. I can upload a broken file with random binary content and it will go through.

Answer (score 3):

Update your code to reflect
For `mp3` - `mpga` is used.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'song' => 'required|mimes:mpga,wav',
]);
```

Comment: it throws a validation error message saying 'The song must be a file of type: mpga.'

Comment: it throws a validation error message saying'The song must be a file of type: mpga.'

Comment: Can you post "var_dump" of a File?

Answer (score 2):

Try 'mimes:mpga' for mp3 files. 'mimes:wav' should be fine for wav files.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'song' => 'required|mimes:mpga,wav',
]);
```

check for extension,
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: it throws a validation error message saying'The song must be a file of type: mpga.'

Answer (score 1):

In version 5.5 of Laravel:

**It is not the correct form, since it is a generic validation, BUT right now it is the only one that works to validate that only mp3 has been made.**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'audio' => 'required|mimetypes:application/octet-stream',
]);
```

Comment: This is plain stupid. `application/octet-stream` is a generic mime type and has nothing to do with audio validation at all.

Comment: It may have been stupid, but it is a solution to allow only mp3. Indicate the solution because I have not found another.

Comment: So you don't validate anything, you simply turn off the validation. How does that relate to the OP's question?

Comment: As I have indicated, in this way it only allows me to load audios with an "mp3" extension. Indicates the correct form and what works, and closes the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
    'file_mp3' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'mp3') {
            $fail(':attribute must be .mp3!');
        }

    }]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers above are correct. My case was that I forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form tag as follows:

```
<form action="some url" method="some method" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   stuff
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'song' => 'required|mimes:audio/mpeg',
]);
```

...and it worked, it validated the mp3 file correctly, thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: You did not validate anything. According to your validation method, [this](https://giphy.com/gifs/cinema-audrey-hepburn-bat-1uZ9jRb57abxm) is a cat.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, but I found the answer for me in this article.

http://www.thedevlogs.com/laravel-custom-validation-mp3-ogg-extension-files-only/

Laravel's getMimeType() is based on the native mime_content_type() method, which has problems detecting certain mp3 files.

Your best bet is to use a custom MIME detector like this to do the job.

So, here is what I did that worked for me. First I opened the file:
**\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

And, in the boot method I added the following code:

```
public function boot()
{
    //Added by B.Singh
    Validator::extend('mp3_ogg_extension', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

        if(!empty($value->getClientOriginalExtension()) && ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'mp3' || $value->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'ogg')){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

So in your request use this way:

```
public function rules()
{         
    $rules = [ 
       'example' => 'required|mp3_ogg_extension'
    ];

    return $rules;
}    

public function messages()
{         
    $messages = [ 
       'example.mp3_ogg_extension' => 'REQUIRED WITH VALIDATION, YEAH'
    ];

    return $messages;
}
```

If it is not clear, you can ask!