# Laravel 7 Incorrect MIME Type Detected

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types, laravel-7, ogg

Laravel 7 on PHP 7 is detecting incorrect MIME type of `application/octet-stream` for .ogg extension.

Here is the applicable file request dump:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1274 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "03 - See You Tonite.ogg"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
```

Anybody know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you sure it is really a ogg file (it plays?) and not some other file just renamed to ogg.

Comment: Yep, it's a valid file that plays.

Comment: And your validation code?

Comment: 'audio' => 'sometimes|mimes:mpeg,mpga,mp3,ogg,wav|max:8000',

Comment: Try looking over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39597911/6160662) for some solution

Comment: use this to know your file mimetype using terminal `file -b --mime example.ogg 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Yes, the file is audio/ogg; charset=binary

Answer (score 1):

Check your mime type file first:

```
 return $request->file('field_name')->getMimeType();
```

Now you can add the following code in the boot method in AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
       
        Validator::extend('ogg_extension', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
             
            if(!empty($value->getClientOriginalExtension()) && ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'ogg')){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
             
        });
    }
```